# Pandas library makes ' 'module' object has no attribute ' error each week or two

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, numpy

Maybe someone had same issue as i do have with pandas library. It stops working each week or two and i do not know where is the problem. It always shows an error that `module object has no attribute...`  and each time there is a different attribute named. 
Adding picture with an error [image]

Comment: Just update... `pip install --upgrade pandas`

Comment: I do this each week or two weeks... it is not a solution